# Parse Test Data not saving

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am new to swift coding and am following a youtube tutorial just to familiarize myself with it. I am trying to use Parse and following their direction to Test the SDK and save the test data. I could not find libz.dylib
libsqlite3.dylib but I was informed by someone on here libz.tbd and libsqlite3.tbd took their place I added this into my app but for some reason Parse does not show any data. Any one happen to have any advice?

Comment: is this iOS or Mac OS X? Does the app build? What code are you using? What errors do you see?

Comment: The app builds successfully, IOS 9 and I don't see any errors within the code. {    let testObject = PFObject(className: "TestObject")
       testObject.setObject(["bar"], forKey: "Foo")
        testObject.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(self, selector: nil)    }

Comment: I did find the following warning:

Comment: ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'

Comment: check my update code

Comment: You should use a save method that actually tells you what happened, particularly if there is an error. don't just set a target and no action selector...

Answer (score 0):

Replace those `libz.dylib libsqlite3.dylib` by `libz.tbd and libsqlite3.tbd`

Make sure you connect your parse account with your project by adding in your **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method

```
Parse.setApplicationId("",
    clientKey: "")
```

**Don't forget to import Parse**

Then try:

```
let object = PFObject(classname:"")   //<---- add the classname that you want 
object["bar"] = "food"
object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (Success:Bool, __error_:NSError?) -> Void in 
   if __error_ == nil 
  {
       // save 
  }
  else
  { 

    // display error 
 }

 })
```

Comment: it builds just nothing saves with that code. Parse is imported and the account is connected

Comment: I think Im just going to delete the App and start for the beginning it builds again and nothing saves

Comment: does either of the following warnings help                                                     ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'

Comment: ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F(1)'

Comment: maybe start a new project